# Is it theoretically possible to watch events of 1985 with near light speed travel & a big enough telescope?

Tags: special-relativity, time, observers

James Webb allows us to see stars as they were thousands of years ago. So what about seeing Earth of 37 years ago.

For nostalgic purposes I’d like to watch myself aged 12 in 1985, perhaps outside on Christmas Day playing on my new BMX bike.

Presumably to see the light from 37 years ago, said telescope would need to be 37 light years away.

But how could this theoretically be possible? Please discuss the speed of travel, size of telescope, and any problems with the theory.

Comment: Your question needs more focus. Please ask one conceptual question at a time. The main part of the question you have answered, in that you would need to (now) be 37 light-years away. thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a mirror, for some reason . . .

Comment: @m4r35n357 How would a mirror help? It would take twice as long for the light to reach a mirror then bounce back to me on earth. Could you clarify your thinking?

Comment: @josephh The question is focussed. “How could I achieve the goal of seeing myself in 1985?”

Comment: It is what I use when I want to see myself.  Think about it, taking "twice as long" is not an issue.  You simply place it half as far away as you think I think it needs  to be!